# First received Hyperledger Fabric frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 1503010002

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

Please help me to look at this mistake. Thank you very much.
I used the same method to modify the IP fabric-sdk-java example is successful, but I switched to another order server, to modify IP, and the secret key file address, is wrong
My stack information：

```html
09:51:03.441 [grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-2] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x35dec18c, L:/192.168.2.10:51815 - R:/10.60.248.45:7050] OUTBOUND GO_AWAY: lastStreamId=0 errorCode=1 length=77 bytes=4669727374207265636569766564206672616d6520776173206e6f742053455454494e47532e204865782064756d7020666f7220666972737420352062797465...
org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Channel foo sendDeliver failed on orderer orderer.example.com. Reason: INTERNAL
 at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient.sendDeliver(OrdererClient.java:295)
 at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Orderer.sendDeliver(Orderer.java:172)
 at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.seekBlock(Channel.java:1198)
 at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getLatestBlock(Channel.java:1274)
 at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getLastConfigIndex(Channel.java:1097)
 at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigurationBlock(Channel.java:1028)
 at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:949)
 at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.initialize(Channel.java:676)
 at com.foresealife.blockchain.controller.ChaincodeController.query(ChaincodeController.java:246)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL
 at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526)
 at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:380)
 at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:419)
 at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$100(ClientCallImpl.java:60)
 at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:493)
 at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:422)
 at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:525)
 at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
 at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:102)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 ... 1 more
Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 1503010002
 at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.connectionError(Http2Exception.java:85)
 at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.verifyFirstFrameIsSettings(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:320)
 at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:221)
 at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:413)
 at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
 at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
 at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
 at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
 at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
 ... 1 more
09:51:03.466 [grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-2] DEBUG io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler - [id: 0x35dec18c, L:/192.168.2.10:51815 ! R:/10.60.248.45:7050] Sending GOAWAY failed: lastStreamId '0', errorCode '1', debugData 'First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 1503010002'. Forcing shutdown of the connection.
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
 at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504)
 at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:432)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:856)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:362)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:823)
 at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1296)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
 at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.onError(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:573)
 at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:227)
 at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:413)
 at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
 at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
 at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
 at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
 at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Part of my code:

```html
SampleUser peerOrgAdmin = sampleStore.getMember("Org1MSP" + "Admin", "Org1MSP", sampleOrg.getMSPID(),
                    Util.findFileSk(Paths.get("/Users/zhoutuanjie/workspace-new-sz/", "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/",
                            "org1.example.com", format("/users/Admin@%s/msp/keystore", "org1.example.com")).toFile()),
                    Paths.get("/Users/zhoutuanjie/workspace-new-sz/", "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/", "org1.example.com",
                            format("/users/Admin@%s/msp/signcerts/Admin@%s-cert.pem", "org1.example.com", "org1.example.com")).toFile());

            sampleOrg.setPeerAdmin(peerOrgAdmin);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HFClient client = HFClient.createNewInstance();
        try{
            client.setCryptoSuite(CryptoSuite.Factory.getCryptoSuite());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final ChaincodeID chaincodeID;
        chaincodeID = ChaincodeID.newBuilder().setName("qhChaincode004")
                .setVersion("1")
                .setPath("github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/qhChaincode").build();
//        final ChaincodeID chaincodeID;
//        chaincodeID = ChaincodeID.newBuilder().setName("example_cc_go")
//                .setVersion("1")
//                .setPath("github.com/example_cc").build();

        try {
            ChannelConfiguration channelConfiguration = new ChannelConfiguration(new File("/Users/zhoutuanjie/workspace-new-sz/fabric-sdk-java/src/test/fixture/sdkintegration/e2e-2Orgs/channel/foo.tx"));

            client.setUserContext(sampleOrg.getPeerAdmin());

//            File cert = Paths.get("/Users/zhoutuanjie/workspace-new-sz/fabric-sdk-java/src/test/fixture/sdkintegration/e2e-2Orgs/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt").toFile();
            File cert = Paths.get("/Users/zhoutuanjie/workspace-new-sz/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt").toFile();
            Properties ret = new Properties();
            ret.setProperty("pemFile", cert.getAbsolutePath());
            ret.setProperty("trustServerCertificate", "true"); //testing environment only NOT FOR PRODUCTION!
            ret.setProperty("hostnameOverride", "orderer.example.com");
            ret.setProperty("sslProvider", "openSSL");
            ret.setProperty("negotiationType", "TLS");

            Orderer newOrder = client.newOrderer("orderer.example.com", "grpc://10.60.248.45:7050", ret);

            Channel newChannel = client.newChannel("foo");
            newChannel.addOrderer(newOrder);
```

My orderer server log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgBg9.jpg)

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you're asking. What example are you trying to implement and what have you changed?

Comment: My fabric-sdk-java application reported a mistake, which was to access order without creating TLS support when creating a channel, but I didn't know how to solve it. Thank you

Comment: how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, change 'grpc://' with 'grpcs://' in your peer, orderer and eventhub locations URLs. And then restart your hyperledger network.

Comment: this is not work for problem Channel foo sendDeliver failed on orderer orderer.example.com, but it's true if you want to use GRPCS

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/4063#issuecomment-365030890) on a similar GRPC issue suggests that:

> This is usually because the server is using SSL, but the client is not.